# How to wait with function execution until subscription is completed?

Tags: javascript, observable

I want to subscribe to an Observable and then execute another function. My problem is, it takes a moment until the request is finished. However, the code just continues with its execution immediatly *after* the subscription has started.

I need some information that will be there after the Subscription is **complete**. Without that data, transformShopList() will fail. When I run the code, this is what happens.

How can you wait for the Subscription to finish, and then go on with the rest of the statements?

```
this.observable3.subscribe(
  ...
);
// wait here?
this.transformShopList();
```

Comment: Have you tried a `.then()`? `this.observable3.subscribe().then(function(){ .. })`

Comment: No, would other statements after the then(...) also wait for .then to be finished?

Comment: You should include the functions you want to execute after the `.subscribe` is complete, inside the `.then()`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have this problem whatever you do in Javascript. Asynchronous tasks must be **chained**. Either with `Promise`, `Observable` or callback functions.

The right code is

```
this.observable3.subscribe((...) => {
  ...
  this.transformShopList();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An observable emits an event and your subscription receives it.  Move your transform shop list inside the subscription response and it will execute when the observable emits.

https://angular.io/guide/observables